# Error installing libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, libv8

I tried installing libv8 v3.16.14.3 using the following command

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'
```

I got the following output.

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:58:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
    from C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:42:in `block in build_libv8!'
    from C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `chdir'
    from C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `build_libv8!'
    from C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
```

I am confused how to resolve this issue.

Can someone please help me out here please.

Comment: type at ur console python -V, if command unknown, or version below 2 - install from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)

Python installed in your system ??

Comment: No i guess. I will install and try the same. Thanks anyways :-)